# "object got multiple values for keyword argument" when writing database using dictionary

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django model with fields: `city`, `country_name` and `country_code`.

I have a dictionary which has more than 8 key-value pairs; I want use only 3 and write into database.

But I am getting an error

**`ModelBase object got multiple values for keyword argument 'country_code'`**

my code:

```
dicty = {
    'city': u'Mountain View', 'continent_code': u'NA', 'region': u'CA',
    'charset': 0, 'area_code': 650, 'longitude': -122.05740356445312,
    'country_code3': u'USA', 'latitude': 37.4192008972168, 'postal_code': u'94043',
    'dma_code': 807, 'country_code': u'US', 'country_name': u'United States'
}

m = Logger(city='city',country_name='country_name',country_code='country_code',**dicty)
m.save()
```

Comment: You're passing in `country_code` more than once, once as an argument and once in the dictionary. What are you actually trying to achieve with that?

Comment: Try `m = Logger(**dicty)`

Comment: Hi Joachim, I have only 3 fields in my model so I want filter dictionary data and write only 3 values.

Comment: If you want to filter the dictionary you can do it like that: `{k: v for k, v in dicty.iteritems() if k in ["wanted_key1", "wanted_key2"]}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing two arguments for `country_code`:

```
m = Logger(city='city', country_name='country_name',
           country_code='country_code', **dicty)
#          ^ here                       ^ and in here
```

So you get both `country_code = "country_code"` *and* `country_code = u"US"`. If you only want to pass three values from the dictionary, do:

```
m = Logger(city=dicty['city'], country_name=dicty['country_name'],
           country_code=dicty['country_code'])
```